# Can't use CenturyGothic font with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I'd like to use CenturyGothic in Tkinter form but it doesn't change font...

My code:

```
import tkinter
import datetime
import time


app = tkinter.Tk()
app.title("Clock")
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.minsize(640,480)
def middle_screen():
    w = 1280
    h = 720
    ws = app.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = app.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
middle_screen()
app.configure(bg='white')

CurrentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"))
label_time = tkinter.Label(app, text=CurrentTime, bg='white', fg='black')
label_time.configure(font='GothicCentury 48 bold')
label_time.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

The result:
[image: Result]

What it should be:
[image: What it should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
label_time.configure( font=("Century Gothic", 48, 'bold'))
```

Comment: Thaks you so muchhh